# Spring: where does it get ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, web

I have a Spring project with the following piece of code:

```
@Autowired
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    // Wiring
    AppContext.setApplicationContext(ctx);
}
```

It sets the `applicationContext`. From the debugger I can see the `ctx` is of type `AnnotationEmbeddedWebApplicatoinContext`.

I tried to look at call stack to see where it gets this type of context rather than some other kind. But I failed to trace it. All calls before this were Spring internal calls.

Where does it get this type? this info? From the `pom.xml` or somewhere else?

My related `pom` entries:

```
<!-- Spring Boot Web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Is that when Spring sees `spring-boot-starter-web`, it uses that kind of `applicationContext`?

Comment: pom.xml is for building your application with maven. It is absolutely not involved at run time. _All calls before this were SPRING internal calls._ `ApplicationContext` is a Spring class. Those internal calls are what you should be looking at. You haven't told us what class has this `setApplicationContext` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using spring-boot (http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) which is an opinionated way of configuring and using a spring application. The advantage of using boot is that their philosophy is convention over configuration so with few code you get a lot. This means that you don't have the need to create and define verbose xml config files (or java config files) because boot does that for you.

If you want to override some of the autoconfiguration of spring-boot I recommend you to check their docs:

- Main docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/index.html
- Customizing autoconf: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html

Comment: oh, so this is my case right? This project is using this spring-boot to simplify a lot of configurations. The trade-off is not as flexible as traditional way.

Comment: i would say that is flexible enough, if you need to change some of the (auto)configuration provided by spring-boot you can do it.